# ddslick image dropdown, style formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, dropdown

I am using ddSlick to have a dropdown selection with images How do I remove the caret on the upper right?

[image]

```
 $('#myLanguage').ddslick({
     data:ddData,
     width:100,
     imagePosition:"center",
     background: "#CCCCCC",
     onSelected: function(selectedData){
     }   
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not find any options you can pass to the plugin itself, so probably the easiest way would be by adding `display: none` to the class `.dd-pointer` (See example below)

```
.dd-pointer {
    display: none;
}
```

Since the space for the caret isn't needed anymore, you also might want to center the text of the dropdown trigger by applying `text-align: center` like below:

```
.dd-select {
    text-align: center;
}
```